# Why does mocking 'open' and returning a FileNotFoundError raise AttributeError: __exit__?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, try-except

Testing by mocking `open` with a `FileNotFoundError` raises `AttributeError: __exit__`. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

The following code opens a simple text file. If the file is missing it generates a default value. It has been checked by regular running and it appears to be working perfectly.

**so_main.py**

```
import os

import so_config


def load_savelocation():
    path = os.path.join(so_config.ROOT, so_config.SAVELOCATION_FN)
    savelocation_path = os.path.normpath(path)
    try:
        with open(savelocation_path) as f:
            so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH = f.readline()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH = so_config.ROOT
```

**so_config.py**

```
import os

ROOT, _ = os.path.split(__file__)
SAVELOCATION_PATH = None
SAVELOCATION_FN = 'savelocation.ini'
```

The unittests are a different story. I've mocked the `open` command in `so.main`. `test_so_main.py` has two tests: One for normal opening of a file which is present and a second to test the `FileNotFoundError` handling.

The first test of regular file opening `test_read_path_from_disk_file_into_config_py` works fine.

The second test fails because the `FileNotFoundError` raises `AttributeError: __exit__`. 
I can set `self.mock_open.return_value` to `FileNotFoundError` or I can set it to `'garbage'`. It doesn't make any difference.

**test_so_main.py**

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import so_config
import so_main


class TestReadSaveLocation(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.savelocation_path = so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH
        self.root = so_config.ROOT
        so_config.ROOT = 'program root'
        p = mock.patch('so_main.open')
        self.mock_open = p.start()
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)

    def tearDown(self):
        so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH = self.savelocation_path
        so_config.ROOT = self.root

    def test_read_path_from_disk_file_into_config_py(self):
        self.mock_open().__enter__().readline.return_value = 'data files location'
        so_main.load_savelocation()
        self.assertEqual('data files location', so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH)

    def test_missing_file_defaults_savelocation_to_program_root(self):
        self.mock_open.return_value = FileNotFoundError
        so_main.load_savelocation()
        self.assertEqual('program root', so_config.SAVELOCATION_PATH)
```

I'm running Python 3.5.2 via PyCharm 2016.2.1 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mock the function to *return* an exception instead of *raise* it.

Try using `side_effect` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)):

```
self.mock_open.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
```