# guaranteed unit test fixture for non-existent file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, directory-structure

Imagine one writes a unit test for `handle` for a case when `path` does not exist:

```
def handle(path):
   try:
      with open(path) as f:  
          pass
   except FileNotFoundError:
       raise FileNotFoundError(path)
```

I would write something like below for such test:

```
import pytest

def test_handle_on_non_existent_path(): 
    x = "abc" # some unbelievable string
    with pytest.raises(FileNotFoundError):
        handle(x)
```

My question is what is a better way to generate non-existent path for a unit-test.

My ideas are:

- force delete a temporary file
- genereate a random string like uuid?

`"abc"` is fairly concise, but in principle does guarantee path does not exist.

Update: in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986259/how-to-properly-unit-test-filenotfounderror) `x` is `"no_exist.txt"`

Comment: A uuid is guaranteed to be unique, seems suitable. Well close enough to unique that it shouldn't matter

Comment: @IainShelvington why no answer?

Comment: Combined with e.g. `tmpdir` fixture, a `uuid.uuid4()` is IMO a reliable answer. One can also use smth like `pyfakefs` that can create an FS mock that doesn't contain any file if not created explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to unit-testing, it seems your intent is to test the behaviour of your code for the case that `open(path)` will throw a `FileNotFoundError`.  Your approach is to have the code actually perform the `open` call, but with a non-existent path name.  This has some disadvantages: As you already noticed, the dependency on the real file system brings the question how to create a value for `path` that reliably does not exist as a file on the file system.  But, there is another point, namely that you are not even sure that there could not exist another problem with the file system, for example some permission related problem, which could cause some other exception to be raised (`OSError`).

Put together, performing the call to `open` itself means you are not in full control of what happens.  Therefore, a better approach can be, for this unit test case, to mock `open` and make your mock raise the `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Certainly a mock is great alternative! I'm always hestant to use it as it always seems "self-fulfilling" (you patch it and it breaks as you said), but hey - that is exactly the guarantee I asked for. My points of reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38918979/1758363